# Using multiple conditions (AND) (ANd Not) in SASS IF statement

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have these variables

```
$number: 10;
$color: red;
$theme: light;
```

And I'm trying to make an if statment in one line that contain AND, Not i should use not in my if statment

**If the number is greater than 5**

**And if the color is red at the same time**

**And If the theme value is not dark**

**You must use not**

```
.class {
  @if (($number > 5) and ($color == "red") and not ($theme == "dark")) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

This code it doesn't work i tried withou ( ) and i tried && but also it doesn't work and after i search i found i should use and, and not like in my code but i don't have the correct output

```
.class {
color: red;
}
```

How Can i fix that?

Comment: `not ($theme == "dark")`: I think you mean `$theme != "dark"`?

Comment: @InSync i should use not and i tired like you said but also it didn't give the correct output

Comment: That was a minor suggestion about logic. What you need is to remove the quotes: `@if $number > 5 and $color == red and $theme != dark`. See [the documentations](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/strings) for differences between quoted and unquoted strings.

Comment: @InSync I think you could post this as an answer.

Comment: @Arkellys I think this is a non-reproducible/typo question, which should be closed rather than answered.

Comment: @InSync Alright